# Is my parametrisation correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, parametric

Find a parametrisation $f\ : \ [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ for the line segment from i to 1 + i.

So my answer is $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  defined as follows
f(t) = (1 - t)i + t(1 + i)

Comment: Yeah, this works. So, what is the question?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Looking at the title of the question, i have a feeling the OP might be asking whether the parametrisation is correct.

Comment: Exactly but now I have few more questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the parametrization is correct. In a more general setting, the line segment between $z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C$ is parametrized by $z(t) = z_1 + t(z_2 - z_1)$, with $t \in \left[0,1\right]$. You can check that your parametrization is the same as the one I gave here, with $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = 1+i$.

Comment: can you explain in general why this works ?

Comment: You start at $z_1$. The vector pointing from $z_1$ to $z_2$ is $z_2-z_1$. So $z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$ is some point in the line passing through $z_1$ and $z_2$. If $t=0$ you get $z_1$. If $t=1$ you get $z_2$. If $0<t<1$ you get something inbetween. If $t>1$ you get some point beyond $z_2$. If $t<0$ you get some point before $z_1$.